# How resolve System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException

Tags: winforms, wcf, console-application

When I Self hosting the `WCF` service using console application, It will successfully hosted. But i am trying to use in windows forms client application the below exception should be thrown.

> System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException: 'A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception.'
>   Win32Exception: The system cannot contact a domain controller to service the authentication request. Please try again later.

WCF service:

```
<services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="MessageBehavior" name="WcfService.MessageService">
        <endpoint address="MessageService" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="WcfService.IMessageService" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="localhost:80" />
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8090" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
```

My Base endpoint is : http://localhost:8080

Any help in this ?

Comment: Which binding type does your service use? During the invocation, we might need to provide the credential to call the service, typically the windows accounts in the server.
Please post the complete code of service endpoint, and the binding configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Nettcpbinding secures the communication with message security mode by default, and authenticates the client with window authentication.

```
NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding();
        binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Message;
        binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.Windows;
```

Therefore, we need to provide windows credentials to call the service.

```
ServiceReference1.ServiceClient client = new ServiceReference1.ServiceClient();
            //the windows credentials are the window accounts on the server-side which hosts the service.
            client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = "administrator";
            client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = "123456";
            var result = client.Add(34, 56);
            Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.

Comment: Dear Abraham , I will check with above code But still i am getting exception as The server has rejected the client credentials

Inner Exception: System.Security.Authentication.InvalidCredentialException: The server has rejected the client credentials.
---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The logon attempt failed

Comment: I don't understand why you have two service base addresses above, and one format is not standardized. Also, can you determine which service endpoint you are consuming now? Nettcpbinding doesn't use Http URI.

Comment: First one basemetadata second one is service end point. On my personal computer it works but on my  profession computer still throwing an issue.  Thanks for your timely help , once found the solution ping me in the same. Good night @abraham

Comment: If the windows account (username/password) is incorrect, the error will be thrown. Please ensure your username/password is right. The account containing an empty password is invalid.